# how to extract hardware features used by a method?

Tags: android, apk

I am analyzing android apk files. and I have the permissions needed for every method in the application, I want to use these permissions to know what hardware is needed for each method, is there a way to do this using permissions, or there is another approach? (I know about uses-feature in android manifest. It's problem is it doesn't say which method uses the feature, and what I need is to know the method that uses the feature)